# Secure permutation of $E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ as a set for an elliptic curve $E$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$

Tags: elliptic-curves, protocol-design, implementation, cryptocurrency, protocol-analysis

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. For simplicity, let the group $E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ be of prime order.

Assume that I know how to construct an efficiently computable permutation of $E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ as a set, that is, just a bijective map $\phi: E(\mathbb{F}_q) \to E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ rather than a group homomorphism. Moreover, $\phi$ satisfies the property that for every non-zero point $P \in E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ nobody knows the discrete logarithm $\log_{\phi(P)}(P)$. Finally, $\phi$ is supposed to be different from the translation map $P \mapsto P + P_0$ with respect to a fixed point $P_0 \in E(\mathbb{F}_q)$.

I encounter the given primitive in [CryptoNote white paper](https://www.bytecoin.org/old/whitepaper.pdf) (page 17) and in [Monero documentation](https://monerodocs.org/cryptography/asymmetric/key-image/) in their signature deployed on the curve Ed25519.

Do you know other cryptographic protocols in which the permutation $\phi$ is used ? What other properties must $\phi$ have to be secure ? Is there a technology, which applies $\phi$ on an elliptic curve of $j$-invariant $0$ ?

Thank you in advance for an answer!